# How to flat a string to several columns in pandas?

Tags: pandas

```
fruit = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['apple: 1 orange: 2 pear: 3']})
```

I want to flat the dataframe and get the below format:

apple  orange pear
1         2    3

Thanks

Comment: is every value an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making your live extremely difficult if you work with multiple values in a single field. You can basically use none of the pandas functions because they all assume they data in a field belong together and should stay together.

For instance with

```
In [10]: fruit = pd.Series({'apple': 1, 'orange': 2, 'pear': 3})

In [11]: fruit
Out[11]: 
apple     1
orange    2
pear      3
dtype: int64
```

you could easily transform your data as in

```
In [14]: fruit.to_frame()
Out[14]: 
        0
apple   1
orange  2
pear    3

In [15]: fruit.to_frame().T
Out[15]: 
   apple  orange  pear
0      1       2     3
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is really helpful.

Comment: If you are interested in learning the basics   the [10 Minutes intro to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html) is quite good. And if you are willing to invest some time I can really recommend https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781491957653/ by the author of pandas. This is what got me started. :)